# Why button is being clicked twice

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle button-div" data-toggle="buttons">
     <label class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="alert('option1');">
       <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off"> Option 1
     </label>
     <label class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="alert('option2');">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Option 2
     </label>
</div>
```

Hello, when I click any of these radio buttons, it seems to be clicked twice. Because I get two similar alerts. How to fix this? Bootstap 5.

Currently, I get an alert "option 1", then again "option 1".

Expected: only one alert "option 1".

Comment: @rayhatfield, the accepted answer in that thread does not solve the issue

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't solve the issue? It both explains its cause and provides a suggested solution. There are other solutions, like stopping event propagation/bubbling, etc., but the suggestion does fix it.

Comment: The accepted answer did not solve the double alert effect. But, the simple change "onclick" to "change" fixed double alerting. No complex bubbling was needed.

Comment: I’m not going to argue with you, but I verified the accepted answer *does* solve the double alert in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change the "onclick" action to "change" action. Thank you all for the support towards the solution.

Answer (score -2):

Your on click is causing the issue, wrapping it in a function will do the trick, hopefully someone can add and explain why this happens as I have completely forgotten, and can't for the life of me remember.

You basically want to change your code from this

```
onclick="alert('option1');"

// to this

onclick="() => alert('option1');"
```